# How to use chatterbot for multiple tags

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, chatterbot

I am using chatterbot for chatbot development. I have dataset in which there are 4 categories, my task is to handle if abc has low confidence then it match correct answer ,else dce category match , so how I can implement new logic adapter for such kind of problem.

Comment: you use a NLP engine like DIalogflow, RASA etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this

https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/index.html#best-match-adapter

https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/multi-logic-adapter.html

Are you using any intents or entities for the user response?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this kind of information. I am not using intents or entities. Data is stored in csv file that I have read through pandas, In csv file there are 4 different categories like abc, def, cgh, efg , my task is to build new lagic adapter for each category and call them using perticular condition. condition like if abc has confidence <0.6 then it should show output as abc related task .